# Best way to rewrite an mvc application to an angular architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, rewrite, angular2

We have an mvc application that we would like to gradually move to an angular platform. It is a wizard style app with 6-8 pages.

We currently have a classic mvc layout. We would like to move to an angular2 project structure.

Our current approach is to rewrite one page at a time, but we also have to provide improvements to business and it is not an option to stop delivering business value while rewriting.

The problem with this approach is it hard to find time to rewrite a big chunk of the application.

Would it be a better approach to pull angular into the MVC site so we could start out with something like a mini-SPA and when all the widgets on a page have been transitioned it would be simpler to transition the page over to the angular project structure

Comment: [Why do you want to do this rewrite?](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

Comment: Why don't you just leave the original app online while you perform the rewrite, and then cut over to the new angular app when the rewrite is done?

Comment: @RobertHarvey since this has low priority from PO we still have to deliver features and bug fixes so unless we can write the new features in angular it will probably never happen

Comment: Well, the two architectures are pretty much diametrically opposed.

Answer (score 1):

I omit the part about [Why do you want to do this rewrite](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) from Dan Pichelman since it's already address in his link.

You can see in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762515/is-angular2-mvc) post, that angular2 is more component oriented.

This mean that if you want a proper rewrite of you application, you probably need some "redesign". And since it's about components, you first need to identify the components of your application to be able to use them properly accross the different pages of your application.

Now you're talking about an app of 6-8 pages. If it's not some dirty thousand lines of code each ones, this probably won't be too much off effort.
But if you have some specific usage case that don't match the standard usage of Web, i suggest you to check if you will be able to do it in AngularJS2.

Some migration to newer technologies can contains some hellish parts because the new technology wasn't made to be use for the specific case it was used. If this happens you may need to change how your functionnality is implemented to match to something that fit with the new technologies.

TL;DR don't try to adapt the framework to you, but adapt your code to the framework.